# Build a Cocoa UI for OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, uistoryboard

I'm trying to build a UI which look like this:

[image]

I'm using a storyboard  with Xcode but I don't know how to start. I think a need different view in the window to manage button, text and tree but I don't know I to do it. I have try to use a split view but it gave me only 2 views instead of 3.

Any help in Cocoa and storyboard is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I have no experience with storyboards, so I’m not sure how that’d go, but as far as I know, you’d go about doing this by creating a toolbar, which will automatically attach to the top, and put some buttons there; then put a table view (inside a scroll view) in the main area, place it appropriately, and tell it to resize when the window resizes; then place a label at the bottom, and in your code, [set the content border thickness](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SettingWindowAppearance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000232-SW2) for the bottom.

Comment: @icktoofay if any better solution than storyboard. Let me know. I never develop UI on OSX. On QT, throught Qtcreator you can visually create stuff but OSX seems more complicated

Comment: I don’t even know what a storyboard is, so I can’t say whether what I suggested is ‘better’ or not, but I did just describe how to do it in Interface Builder.

Comment: Use NSTreeController, NSOutlineView and data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see where you'd want to use an `NSSplitView` but the UI you're attemting to create is trivial -

- A plain `NSWindow` with the toolbar items configured as per your screenshot.
- An `NSOutlineView` for the tree view with the three columns,
- the [content border](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SettingWindowAppearance.html) of the window sized accordingly to make room for the label you intend to put at the bottom of the window.

As mentioned in the comments one way to populate the outline view would be to use an `NSTreeController` and [Cocoa bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html). That's probably the only slightly more complicated bit about this UI..